# Value error when calculating standard deviation on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need the standard deviation of column `distance` for each row in my dataframe.

Dataframe `df_stats`:

```
                                a1/a2   distance  mean_distance
date_time                                                      
2021-10-29T21:00:00+00:00  105.007574  -2.530492       0.234318
2021-10-29T22:00:00+00:00  104.459527  -5.232787       0.012537
2021-10-29T23:00:00+00:00  104.648467   1.807101       0.093432
2021-10-30T00:00:00+00:00  104.758201   1.048046       0.164502
2021-10-30T01:00:00+00:00  104.820132   0.591004       0.246095
2021-10-30T02:00:00+00:00  104.474062  -3.307024      -0.194917
2021-10-30T03:00:00+00:00  104.284146  -1.819483      -0.231843
2021-10-30T04:00:00+00:00  104.072383  -2.032697      -0.249918
2021-10-30T05:00:00+00:00  103.690546  -3.675699      -0.484996
2021-10-30T06:00:00+00:00  103.755979   0.630837      -0.823674
2021-10-30T07:00:00+00:00  102.721667 -10.018720      -1.181811
2021-10-30T08:00:00+00:00  102.998153   2.687995      -1.015365
2021-10-30T09:00:00+00:00  103.236159   2.308109      -0.876012
2021-10-30T10:00:00+00:00  103.471932   2.281216      -0.930593
2021-10-30T11:00:00+00:00  103.376928  -0.918579      -1.142659
2021-10-30T12:00:00+00:00  103.587805   2.037809      -1.110613
2021-10-30T13:00:00+00:00  104.359756   7.424508      -0.468987
2021-10-30T14:00:00+00:00  104.612493   2.418853      -0.383811
2021-10-30T15:00:00+00:00  104.607392  -0.048755      -0.562828
2021-10-30T16:00:00+00:00  104.846049   2.278849      -0.203495
2021-10-30T17:00:00+00:00  104.997437   1.442872      -0.004827
```

Trying to do it this way:

```
df_stats['std'] = df_stats.distance.std(axis=1)
```

But I get this error:

```
No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Use `df_stats['std'] = df_stats.distance.std()`

Comment: Then I get one and the same value in all rows

Comment: yop, it is expected, because std of column is scalar. Do you need something else?

Comment: ```axis=..``` specifies the axis along which the calculation is computed.  ```axis=0``` means along the rows ```index``` in pandas), and axis=1 along the columns. Since you have 1 column here ->  ```df_stats.distance.std(axis=1)``` , it's a series and it logically fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it not working?

Because `axis=1` is for `std` per columns, but you count `Series`, `df_stats.distance`, there is no columns so error raised.

If use `std` of column, output is scalar:

```
print (df_stats.distance.std()) 

df_stats['std'] = df_stats.distance.std()
```

If need processing per multiple columns then `axis=1` count `std` per rows:

```
df_stats['std'] = df_stats[['distance','a1/a2','mean_distance']].std(axis=1)
```

If need `std` per some datetimes, e.g. days:

```
df_stats['std'] = df_stats.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d')).distance.transform('std')
```